# Red Pitaya normal operating temperature

Tags: redpitaya

I've just had my Red Pitaya running for two nights now, but I've already noticed that just having it booted up for a while makes the board quite hot.  Is that normal or should I be cooling it?

Answer (score 2):

This is normal and there is nothing to be worried about as long as your Red Pitaya is not placed in the environment that exceeds 30 degC, being covered or placed into enclosure. In such case the heatsink or small fan should be used for cooling.
For more details please read environmental conditions section inside hardware specifications.

[Main wiki page](http://wiki.redpitaya.com/index.php?title=Main_Page)